# Sound not coming from headphones when plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, cinema-display

## Material:

- MacBook Air 13-inch (MBA), Mid 2013, 1.7 GHz Intel Core i7, 8GB RAM, OS X 10.10.2;
- 24-inch LED Cinema Display (3 cables: power, USB and Thunderbolt);
- iPhone 5 (and above headphones, with integrated mic).

## Problem/issue:

- when the a/m MBA is connected to the Cinema Display and I plug the headphones, the sound still comes out of the Cinema Display, instead of the headphones;
- when the a/m MBA is NOT connected to the Cinema Display and the headphone is plugged in, sound is cut from the MBA speakers and is redirected to the headphones as it should be;
- in order to get the sound redirected to the headphones, I now have to launch System Preferences, Sound and switch manually to Headphone port;
- I also tried to change the headphones, but the problem remains.

This started maybe a week ago (but after upgrading to 10.10.2, from 10.10.1, not saying that the upgrade is at fault, though).

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical for sound to come out of the Cinema Display when connected?

Comment: Yes Buscar, but if one connects the headphones, this should override it. At least that is how it was up to last week...

Comment: @pdeli - what's changed with your setup since last week that may have caused this (new hardware, software updates etc.)? Chances are *something's* changed if it all worked as you wanted before last week...

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly - I found the problem: in System Preferences -> Sound -> Output, when the headphones are plugged in, Display Audio was selected. I just had to click on Headphones and now, when the headphones are connected, sound switches to them and when unplugged, it reverts to the display speakers. Must've clicked once and did not remember... (I doubt the system switched on its own ;-) )